# vector of historical highs of another vector

Tags: r

I searched at the forums but I could not find an answer for this.

I am looking for a way to convert
c(1,3,4,2,7,12,6,8,15)
to 
c(1,3,4,4,7,12,12,12,15) using no loops.

It can be defined as a vector of historical highs of another vector.

This is an example, my data length will be fairly long.

thanks a lot,
Emre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cummax` from `base R`

```
cummax(v1)
#[1]  1  3  4  4  7 12 12 12 15
```

#### data

```
v1 <-  c(1,3,4,2,7,12,6,8,15)
```